# Should I be getting reimbursed for travel miles?

Tags: united-states, expenses, travel

I apologize if this question is stupid or obvious, but I'm relatively new to the workplace. I just recently turned 18 and have now started traveling domestically and internationally to support our clients. Often times I will be assigned support locally (in Las Vegas) where I will need to make about a 40 mile haul down to the strip.

Should I be getting reimbursed for my miles round trip? All in all I'm spending a lot of money on gas and I feel like I should be getting some kind of compensation. The person to normally ask about this issue is out of the office this week (accident), but I'm just trying to get a sense of if this would be seen as standard in the industry.

Comment: It's so common in the US that the IRS has a fixed rate per mile for reimbursement that most companies follow. Right now I think it's 65 cents per mile.

Comment: http://www.irs.gov/2014-Standard-Mileage-Rates-for-Business,-Medical-and-Moving-Announced

Comment: The gas is only part of the extra costs. It may seem like you're "making money" with the reimbursement rate since it will likely exceed your gas cost, but they've done all the sums, and you're probably losing.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - Its better then nothing.  Just be prepared to document the costs if you go tax write off route.

Comment: @Ramhound Sure. I was just pointing out to the OP that there's not much advantage in encouraging miles on the company- it's going to be about a wash. Almost like a reverse mortgage.

Comment: and check you car insurance - you might not be covered for using it for "work" as opposed to commuting you don't want to find that out after an accident

Answer (score 9):

> I'm just trying to get a sense of if this would be seen as standard in the industry.

Car mileage is a common enough reimbursement that the [IRS has a specific yearly rate for it](http://www.irs.gov/2014-Standard-Mileage-Rates-for-Business,-Medical-and-Moving-Announced). In 2014, this rate is 56 cents/mile.

> Should I be getting reimbursed for my miles round trip?

Generally companies provide reimbursement when you drive your personal vehicle for reasons other than personal reasons.

However keep in mind this is going to vary for your specific company, state, and situation. The only way you are going to know for sure is to ask your boss or expense person.

Answer (score 1):

I recently received an offer for a consulting company and they pay mileage for any miles **further** than your typical office.  So if your office is 20 miles away, and you have to work at a site that is 10 miles further away, you will get reimbursed for 10 miles (or 20 round-trip), but not the 20 (or 40) that it would have taken to get to your typical office.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what you were being told.  The IRS Does not require them to pay you for the milage, but the IRS will allow them to write it off of taxes.  The IRS will also allow you to write off the extra milage if you are not reimbursed or the difference if you are reimbursed less than the amount the IRS would allow you to deduct.  So if you were reimubrsed 50 but the IRS would have allowed you to deduct 100 you could deduct the 50 you were not reimbursed for.

Comment: Understood, I suppose she was referring to the rate at which miles were reimbursed being set by the IRS.

Comment: That could be because if they reimburse for more than the allowed amount it becomes income for you.